# how to deal with quotes in bookmarklets

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

this is a script i found for writing jQuery bookmarklets and i've added three lines of code to it. the problem is jQuery code has lots of quotes (for selectors) and as i have to put the bookmarklets in a **href="javascript:code"** everything gets messed up with the href's double quotes.
here is what my code looks like, i tried to escape double quotes, in many ways, but none did work. is there a way to deal with this problem?

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){

// the minimum version of jQuery we want
var v = '1.3.2';

// check prior inclusion and version
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v) {
    var done = false;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' + v + '/jquery.min.js';
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
            done = true;
            initMyBookmarklet();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
} else {
    initMyBookmarklet();
}

function initMyBookmarklet() {
    (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
        // your JavaScript code goes here!
        var loc=window.location;
        $('body').append('<form id=\'IDform\' action=\'http:/pourid.3eeweb.com/read.php\' method=\'post\' ><input name=\'url\' type=\'text\' value=\''+loc+'\' /></form>');
        $('#IDform').submit();
    })();
}

 })();">bookmarklet</a>
```

when i click on the bookmarklet link, firebug says: SyntaxError: missing } after function body
but if i run the javascript only(not using an html link) it runs fine.

Comment: Easiest solution is to put the code in an external js file and have the bookmarklet add the file to the page.

Comment: Do you actually have line breaks in the html code or is it just in here for pretty factor?

Comment: In your current script, you don't have a problem with quotes in the bookmarklet since you are not using double quotes (used to delimit the HTML attribute) in your code. However, the problem is your comments and newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have `//` comments or line breaks in the attribute. It needs to be one long string.

If you want comments, it needs to be block comments `/*foo*/`

It needs to look like

```
<a href="javascript:document.body.style.color='red';alert('no line breaks');void(0);">foo</a>
```

Comment: Good advice to add, but this doesn't answer anything about the quotes problem, which is what the question is asking (and the title clearly states).

Comment: Haha - yes, indeed - that's like a lifetime in front-end years :)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple ways of doing this, one is to HTML-escape the quotes; `&quot;` or `&#34;` for `"`, `&#39;` for `'`.

The other way, my preferred, is to enter the bookmarklet as a string in JavaScript and attach it to the `<a>` at load time, meaning you don't have any HTML-related problems with it and the browser can do all the encoding for you if you save it.

Also as [sbmaxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310982/sbmaxx) pointed out, you may need to remove the `//` comments. This is because a URI is not expected to have any line breaks and therefore the comment would never end when put onto one line.

Comment: What do you mean by "enter the bookmarklet as a string in JavaScript and attach it to the <a> at load time"?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete comments `//` in your code and it should work ;)